# getServerSideProps not working on prod, works on localhost

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-ecs

I'm currently stuck with a bug that I have been trying to rack my head around for a few days. Basically, I have a dynamic route ([id].tsx) for my /jobs page, that calls serverSideProps to fetch data of that job from my AWS. lambda functions. The data is then used to populate the page before it loads.

The app is dockerized and it works as expected on localhost when running docker run -p 3000:3000 , but fails and gives a 504 error when deployed on AWS ECS. I'm not sure if it's a docker issue, or an issue with my code. Code is as below (parts omitted for brevity)

[id].tsx

```html
export const getServerSideProps = async (context: any) => {
  const { id } = context.query;
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      'https://xxxxxx.yyyyyy.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxx,
      {
        job_id: id,
      },
    );
    const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.data.data)[0];
    const jobStatus = parsedResponse.job_status;

    return {
      props: {
        jobStatus,
      },
    };
  } 
};
```

Dockerfile:

```html
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
Thank you!
```

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure this out?